# Spring boot Integration unit testing NoSuchBeanDefinitionException exception

Tags: spring-boot, spring-integration, spring-mvc-test

I created a sample IntegrationFlow as shown below:

```
@Configuration
@EnableIntegration
@IntegrationComponentScan
@ComponentScan
public class RegisterHostFlow {
  private final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

  @MessagingGateway
  public interface RegisterHostGateway{
      @Gateway(requestChannel = "registerHostInputChannel")
      Host registerHost(Host host);
  }

  @Bean
  public IntegrationFlow httpInboundGatewayFlow() {
      return IntegrationFlows.from("registerHostInputChannel")
            .handle((host, headers) ->  {
                        return host;
            })
            .enrich(e -> e
                    .requestPayload(Message::getPayload)
                    .property("uuid", "34563456345634563456")
                    .property("id", "1234")
            )
            .get();
  }
}
```

I am calling this from a spring MVC controller as below:

```
RegisterHostFlow.RegisterHostGateway registerHostGateway = applicationContext.getBean(RegisterHostFlow.RegisterHostGateway.class);
    Host host1 = registerHostGateway.registerHost(host);
```

When I write a unit test to do some sanity testing as shown below, application fails to load with the error, NoSuchBeanException:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(HostController.class)
@EnableIntegration
@IntegrationComponentScan
public class HostControllerTest {
 @Autowired
 private MockMvc mvc;

@Test
public void  registerHost_passedInHost_returnJson() throws Exception {
    this.mvc.perform(post("/hostservice/v1/hosts").contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON). content('someJsonStringGoesHere'))
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(content().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8));
}
```

Below is the exception I see:

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'registerHostInputChannel' available

at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:982)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.TestDispatcherServlet.service(TestDispatcherServlet.java:65)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain$ServletFilterProxy.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:167)
at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:134)
at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:134)
at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:105)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:134)
at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:134)
at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc.perform(MockMvc.java:155)
```

Any pointers to how to have ApplicationContext autowire the integration beans when in test mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According the `@WebMvcTest` JavaDocs:

```
 * Typically {@code @WebMvcTest} is used in combination with {@link MockBean @MockBean} or
 * {@link Import @Import} to create any collaborators required by your {@code @Controller}
 * beans.
```

You have to make your test class config like:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(HostController.class)
@Import(RegisterHostFlow.class)
public class HostControllerTest {
```

So, this way you have an MVC slice and collaborator in face of Spring Integration and target flow configuration.